# I knew I have to play in a different condition - is the sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, tense

I knew that in the future I have to play in a tough and different condition. I haven't played in that condition yet. Now if I say to someone today that -

*1. I knew I have to play in a different condition. That's why I practiced harder.*

or

*2. I thought I will play in a tough condition. That's why I practiced in mud.*

then are my sentences grammatically correct???

Comment: The problem with these sentences isn't the grammar, but the word "condition", which isn't clear.

Comment: If you knew in the past that you had to do something in the future, the idiomatic way to say it is "I knew I **would have to** play" or "I knew I **would be playing**".  If you had to do it in the past, then it would be "I knew I **had** to play".  But the way you're mixing tenses doesn't work.

Comment: In the past, you knew that in the future, you have to (present tense) play in a generic condition? You can't use tenses this way. Also, how you're using *condition* isn't clear. No, your sentences are not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the first example, you're missing the word **would**. And you play **in different conditions** or **under different conditions** (plural):

> I knew I **would** have to play **under** different condition**s**. That's why I practiced harder.

2. In the second example, you're missing either **would** or **might**, and it's a similar construct to the first. I would say **the** mud, but leaving it out is OK too.

> I thought I **might** play **under** tough condition**s**. That's why I practiced in **the** mud.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you are playing some sports.

If you "play in a different condition", it means that your physical fitness or your health has changed.

If you "play in different conditions", it could mean that it's sunnier, colder or wetter on the field compared to what you have previously experienced. Regardless of how many aspects are different or tough, "conditions" is plural in this case.

1. I knew I will have to play in different conditions. That's why I practiced harder.
2. I thought I will play in tough conditions. That's why I practiced in mud.

Sentence 2 is not clear about if you actually ended up playing in tough conditions or only thought you would.

Comment: Assume that I am from Asia and staying in Europe to play a match. The weather condition in Europe is totally different. I knew the condition would be different. That's why I practiced harder or to play in that condition. Right now I am staying in Europe. If I talk with someone, what should I say?

Comment: Just as the answer says. You should use the plural form "conditions":

"The weather conditions in Europe are..."

"I knew the conditions would be different."

"...play in these conditions."